# How create clock from images which overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make clock ( html / css / javascript ) which slowly animates forward opening the other picture ( the pollution in this case ) .

Example:

[image]

Any ideas how to better unveil the other picture while rotating the stick?

Comment: Is a gif animation out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we won't code it for you, but the heuristic would be something like this:

1. Create a `div` and set the style to include `background: url(myPollutedImage.jpg);`.
2. JavaScript [`SetInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to set an action at pre-determined intervals.
3. At each interval, fill the `div` from #1 with an image that relates to that point in time.  Make sure that the image is a gif or png so that it can have a transparent background thus exposing the background image (pollution).

Good luck!